# Copy or retain NSString parameter?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I'm developing an iOs 4 app with latest SDK and XCode 4.2

I have a question about NSString parameters. This is my class definition:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BlogEntry : NSObject
{
    NSString* title;
    NSString* text;
    NSDate* date;
    NSString* photo;
}

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)titulo text:(NSString*)texto date:(NSDate*)fecha photo:(NSString*)foto;

@end
```

And implementation:

```
#import "BlogEntry.h"

@implementation BlogEntry

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)titulo text:(NSString*)texto date:(NSDate*)fecha photo:(NSString*)foto
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        title = titulo;
        text = texto;
        date = fecha;
        photo = foto;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

May I need to retain `initWithTitle` parameters? Or, may I have to copy them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If ARC, no.  If non-ARC, yes.

For the `NSString` ivars, usually `copy`.  For the `NSDate` ivar, `retain`.  The reason for `copy` with `NSString` is in case an `NSMutableString` is passed in your `init` method.  Copying the parameter prevents it from being mutated by your class.  Thus, it ensures encapsulation.

Comment: Two problems.  Even with ARC, you need to send copy for those properties with copy semantics (ARC only automagically adds retains and releases).  Also, `NSDate` implements `NSCopying` so it should be sent `-copy` too.

Comment: Generalising - anything that implements `NSCopying` should be `copy` semantics. However, I use the rule of thumb 'if it has a mutable subclass, copy it'.